# MP4 Video on MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-installation

I have some MP4 videos that have been produced in-house that I would like to host on our internal MediaWiki (1.26.3). I can't seem to find an extension that is compatible with this version. Am I doing it wrong by looking for an appropriate extension (meaning, is there a native way to display video) or am I simply out of luck until one of the extensions gets updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the VideoPlayer extension (compatible with v1.26.3) with html5 as provider.

To install VideoPlayer extension follow the instructions as in https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VideoPlayer :

1) In your wiki folder, copy the following php code into extensions/VideoPlayer/VideoPlayer.php (create file if does not exist yet):

```
<?php
// See http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VideoPlayer for more information.

$wgExtensionFunctions[] = 'VideoPlayer';
$wgExtensionCredits['parserhook'][] = array(
    'name'          => 'VideoPlayer',
    'description'   => 'Display video players for youtube, dailymotion, vimeo, google, etc...',
    'author'        => 'Joachim Chauveheid',
    'version'       => 1.0 
);

function VideoPlayer() {
    global $wgParser;
    $wgParser->setHook('video', 'renderVideoPlayer');
}

function renderVideoPlayer($input, $args) {
    $url = array();
    $url['allocine']    = 'http://www.allocine.fr/blogvision/%1$s';
    $url['blip']        = 'http://blip.tv/play/%1$s';
    $url['dailymotion'] = 'http://www.dailymotion.com/swf/%1$s?syndication=112040';
    $url['facebook']    = 'http://www.facebook.com/v/%1$';
    $url['gametrailers']= 'http://www.gametrailers.com/remote_wrap.php?mid=%$1s';
    $url['googlevideo'] = 'http://video.google.com/googleplayer.swf?docId=%1$d';
    $url['html5'  ]     = '%1$s';
    $url['metacafe']    = 'http://www.metacafe.com/fplayer/%1$d/' . (isset($args['vid']) ? $args['vid'] : '') . '.swf';
    $url['myspace']     = 'http://mediaservices.myspace.com/services/media/embed.aspx/m=%1$s';
    $url['revver']      = 'http://flash.revver.com/player/1.0/player.swf?mediaId=%1$u';
    $url['sevenload']   = 'http://en.sevenload.com/pl/%1$s/%2$ux%3$u/swf';
    $url['viddler']     = 'http://www.viddler.com/player/%1$s';
    $url['vimeo']       = 'http://www.vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=%1$d&amp;server=www.vimeo.com&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0';
    $url['youku']       = 'http://player.youku.com/player.php/sid/%1$s/.swf';
    $url['youtube']     = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/%1$s?fs=%5$u';


    $flashvars = array();
    $flashvars['revver'] = 'mediaId=%1$u&affiliateId=0';

    $type       = isset($args['type'],$url[$args['type']]) ? $args['type'] : 'youtube';
    $media_url  = isset($url[$type]) ? $url[$type] : $url['youtube'];
    $flash_vars = isset($flashvars[$type]) ? $flashvars[$type] : '';

    $input_array = explode('|', htmlspecialchars($input));
    $id     = current($input_array);
    $width  = (count($input_array) > 1 && is_numeric($input_array[1])) ?     $input_array[1] : 425;
    $height = (count($input_array) > 2 && is_numeric($input_array[2])) ? $input_array[2] : 350;
    $fullscreen = (isset($args['fullscreen']) ? $args['fullscreen'] : 'true') === 'false' ? false : true;

    if(strtolower($type) == 'html5')
    {
        $output = '<video src="'.$id.'" controls style="width:'.$width.'px;height:'.$height.'px"></video><p style="font-size:80%;padding:0;margin:0;">(Right click to control movie)</p>';
        return $output;
    }
    else
    {
        $output = '<object width="%2$u" height="%3$u">'
            .' <param name="movie" value="'.$url[$type].'" />'
            .' <param name="allowFullScreen" value="%4$s" />'
            .' <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />'
            .' <embed src="'.$url[$type] . '" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent"'
            .' width="%2$u" height="%3$u" allowfullscreen="%4$s"'
                    . ' flashvars="' . $flash_vars . '"></embed></object>';
        return sprintf($output,$id,$width,$height,$fullscreen ? 'true' : 'false', (integer)$fullscreen);
    }
}
?>
```

2) Add the following into the wiki's LocalSettings.php:

```
require_once("$IP/extensions/VideoPlayer/VideoPlayer.php");
```

Installation can now be verified through Special:Version (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:Version)

Once VideoPlayer is installed, copy your video(s) to the /resources/assets
 folder in the root directory of your mediawiki project and then write the video tag code into your mediawiki page editor, using 'html5' as provider:

```
<video type="html5">/myWiki/resources/assets/my-video.mp4</video>
```

Cheers!

Comment: I get the control, but the video won't play.

Comment: Please give me further information so i can help you:

Comment: Looks like the extension was installed, but is not finding the video resource. Please give me further information so i can help you: 1) Make sure the video is in the folder and the path to the file is correct in the tag. 2) Using Chrome, right click on the rendered player component and select 'Inspect'. Copy the video element code and paste it here. 3) Pls send me the video code as in your page editor and your LocalSettings.php code if possible.

Comment: You were right. It was the path I was providing that was causing the issue. Thank you for your help! I changed the path to <video type="html5">/resources/assets/my video.mp4</video> and it worked.